# How to replace in jQuery asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

I have this

```
function show()
{
   var d = "myform.htm?pass=" + pass+ "&name=" + name;
   window.location.href = d;
}
```

And on next webform,

```
function getUrlVars()
{
  var vars = [], hash;
  var hashes =  window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
 }
 return vars;
}
```

Now when I call

```
         var b = getUrlVars()["name"];
```

It shows

```
     I%20am%20a%20male
```

It is because it contains space

I tried but not able to get that "what should I write there in `getUrlVars()` "

Comment: javascript `unescape(str_esc)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode use:

```
vars[hash[0]] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decodeURI()` javascript function. This function converts url as you need. For example:

```
decodeURI("I%20am%20a%20male") // shows: I am a male
```